# Dependency Injection for a big number of classes/controllers in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm working on `ASP.Net MVC` project where I use `Autofac` for dependency Injection implementation.

I'm creating Managers classes for business layer and Repository class for database layer.

I have created `BaseController` Class with overloaded constructors to be used for Autofac dependency injection.

**BaseController** //used for authorizations and common actions

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
   protected readonly IManager_A _manager_A;
   protected readonly IManager_B _manager_B;

   public BaseController()
   {}
   public BaseController(IManager_A manager_A)
   {
       this._manager_A = manager_A;
   }
   public BaseController(IManager_B manager_B)
   {
       this._manager_B = manager_B;
   }
   public BaseController(IManager_A manager_A, IManager_B manager_B)
   {
       this._manager_A = manager_A;
       this._manager_B = manager_B;
   }
}
```

**Controller A**

```
public class Controller_A : BaseController
{
    public Controller_A(IManager_A manager_A)
              :base(manager_A)
    {}
}
```

**Controller B**

```
public class Controller_B : BaseController
{
    public Controller_B(IManager_B manager_B)
              :base(manager_B)
    {}
}
```

**Controller A_B**

```
public class Controller_A_B : BaseController
{
    public Controller_A_B(IManager_A manager_A,IManager_B manager_B)
              :base(manager_A,manager_B)
    {}
}
```

suppose I have hundred of Managers classes and each controller use its own managers instances, with this approach I have to create overloaded constructor for each managers instances that I will use in a controller. In some controllers I need to use more than 5 Manager instances *which I think is a sign for bad design*.

How can I create dependency injection using Autofac for such scenario without creating a ton of constructors for `BaseController`???

**Edit**
I removed overloaded constructors from `BaseController` as I don't use Manager Instances in inside. My code controllers became

**BaseController**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
   public BaseController()
   {}
   // code for common action (error handling and authorization)
}
```

**Controller A**

```
public class Controller_A : BaseController
{
    private readonly IManager_A _Manger_A;
    public Controller_A(IManager_A manager_A)
              :base()
    {
       this._Manger_A = manager_A;
    }
}
```

**Controller B**

```
public class Controller_B : BaseController
{
    private readonly IManager_B _Manger_B;
    public Controller_B(IManager_B manager_B)
              :base()
    {
       this._Manger_B = manager_B;
    }
}
```

**Controller A_B**

```
public class Controller_A_B : BaseController
{
    private readonly IManager_A _Manger_A;
    private readonly IManager_B _Manger_B;

    public Controller_A_B(IManager_A manager_A, IManager_B manager_B)
              :base()
    {
       this._Manger_A = manager_A;
       this._Manger_B = manager_B;
    }
}
```

**but still have an issue with controllers that will use many of Manager Instances where controller constructor contains many many parameters!!!**

Comment: [Never create a base controller](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36224308/181087) - use [DI-friendly global filters](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/) instead.

Comment: Loose the basecontroller, that's the source of your trouble, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28310234/3294832